# Android- NumberPicker Changed Appearance

Tags: android

In my application, I'm using a `NumberPicker` to select number and display it in my TextView.

I have two questions regarding this `NumberPicker` thing. First of all,
how can I have a NumberPicker that looks like `image B` rather in `image A`? In Image B, that is how I imagine my NumberPicker would be. So far, this is what I have done:

[image]

My NumberPicker Layout:

```
        <NumberPicker
            android:id="@+id/numberPicker"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="64dp" />

        <LinearLayout
           ...>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_set"
                android:text="Set" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_cancel"
                android:text="Cancel" />
        </LinearLayout>
```

Then this is my Activity:

```
    public void onSomethingButtonClickedToShowDiaolg(View view){
            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MyActivity.this);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.number_selector);
            Button btnSet = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_price_set);
            Button btnCancel = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_price_cancel);
            final NumberPicker numberPicker = (NumberPicker) dialog.findViewById(R.id.numberPicker);
            String[] values = {"5000", "10000", "15000", "20000"};
            numberPicker.setDisplayedValues(values);

            numberPicker.setWrapSelectorWheel(false);
            numberPicker.setOnValueChangedListener(new OnValueChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, int newVal) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    System.out.println("set number: : " + newVal);
                }
            });

            btnSet.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                  @Override
                  public void onClick(View v) {
                      dialog.dismiss();
                   }    
           });
            btnCancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }    
            });

            dialog.show();
        }
```

Then, my other question is this: how can I set in my NumberPicker certain values like... 1000, 3000, 5000, 9000? Because if I use the `setMinValue` and `setMaxValue`.. I can have numbers like 1000, 1001, 1002... And so on.

Any ideas?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8007955/2074990

Comment: i was actually using `setDisplayedValues` but still it wont move or there are no arrows where i can select the values

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/NumberPicker.html. use `Theme.Holo`

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from the docs

- If the current theme is derived from `Theme` the widget presents the
  current value as an editable input field with an increment button
  above and a decrement button below. Long pressing the buttons allows
  for a quick change of the current value. Tapping on the input field
  allows to type in a desired value.
- If the current theme is derived from `Theme_Holo` or `Theme_Holo_Light`
  the widget presents the current value as an editable input field with
  a lesser value above and a greater value below. Tapping on the lesser
  or greater value selects it by animating the number axis up or down  to make the chosen value current. Flinging up or down allows for multiple increments or decrements of the current value. Long pressing on the lesser and greater values also allows for a quick change of the current value. Tapping on the current value allows to type in a
  desired value.

So for Image B use `Theme.Holo`

I have not tried the below. Try it ans use `Theme.holo`

[Is it possible to change the increment of NumberPicker when long pressing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14095656/is-it-possible-to-change-the-increment-of-numberpicker-when-long-pressing)

Answer (score 0):

You may refer to this [library](https://github.com/Prototik/HoloEverywhere) for customizing any view/widgets in android.